# How to Read chunks data from csv and add column then write to the same row in the same file using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am using pandas for read and write csv file. i want to extend column in csv. i am reading csv in chunks, when first chunk read then extend new column data to it and then write that chunk to csv, then receive 2nd chunk add new column data and then write to csv. 
Below is what i want.

```
SN, Name, City
1, John, Washington
2, Eric, Los Angeles
3, Brad, Texas
```

it append the new column data to new rows rather then appending to existing row.

```
SN, Name, 
1, John, 
2, Eric, 
3, Brad, 
4   City
5  Washington
6  Los Angeles
7  Texas
```

**Here is the code.**

```
with open('exampleCsv.csv', 'r') as fieldnames:
    csv_input = pd.read_csv(fieldnames, chunksize=4)
    list_1 = [5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4]
    list_len = len(list_1)//2

    for i in csv_input:
        if list_len%2 == 0:   
            if list_iter == 1:
                i['channel_name'] = list_1[list_len:]
                i.to_csv('exampleCsv.csv', mode='a', index=True)

            elif list_iter == 2:
                i['channel_name'] = list_1[:list_len]
                i.to_csv('exampleCsv.csv', header=None, mode='a', index=True)
        elif list_len%2 == 1:
            i['channel_name'] = list1
            i.to_csv('exampleCsv.csv', header=None, mode='a', index=True)
        list_iter = list_iter + 1
```

Comment: The data could be in Tbs. or may b more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a 6 GB csv file with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas)

Comment: @Vishnudev Thanks for reply, Reading Data in chunks is working,, but when i add new column data into it then write to effect those specific row in csv,, this append new row in the end of csv file,, i want new column in next to city column,